# Does this site allow threatening me and other users who answered my questions?

Tags: discussion

I am reporting attack and harassment. This is today

[image]

This was a few days ago, which has only been partially reversed.

[image]

Replies  to my questions have also been downvoted (by the same user(s)) together with my posts.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/614163/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/611540/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Posts under my other stackexchange accounts have also been attacked (possibly by the same user(s) or like mind).

Does this site allow threatening me and other users who   answered my questions?

Comment: Let's ... be careful with the language. Can you point to places where users of this site have attacked or threatened you? Please keep in mind that votes (up- or down-) are simply clicks on a button that change numbers in a database of some kind; they are not attacks or threats. As you saw, voting fraud is often caught and corrected automatically by the StackExchange system.

Answer (score 11):

No. Threats against other users are not acceptable. If you ever see any such threats, please let the mod team know by flagging.